# Remove files from listing that are created/modified on Saturday

Tags: shell, files, find, ls, timestamps

I am not sure if it is possible.

I do ls -l, it gives all the files in the current directory. Is there a way to say list only files that weren't created/modified on Saturday's with shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this :

```
$ LANG=C find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%p %AA\n' |
    awk '$NF=="Saturday"{next}{$NF=""}1'
```

I assume we don't print files for **all** Saturdays. This is or not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | grep -v -i '^sat'
```

ref: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50236/8141) answer.

Comment: What about files like `saturnism.dat` ?

Comment: @sputnick thanks, edited answer with a `^`

Comment: What about LANG ? My term is in french, your solution will never works

Answer (score 1):

You should select which time you need

- `%y` modification
- `%w` creation
- `%z` change

or any combination:

```
stat * --printf="%n\t%y %z\n" | grep -vF $(date -d "last Saturday" +%F) | cut -f1
```

Also choice what infomation you need and compose `--printf=` line.

Or you can use just `find` command

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart \
     ! -mtime $[$(date +%d)-$(date -d "last Saturday" +%d)]
```